# CI Android Project - gradlew no such file

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I've got the following configuration `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

before_script:
  - cd android
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - ls -la
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
```

however, `gradlew` is missing.

```
ls -la
total 151044
drwxrwxrwx. 5 root root      4096 Nov 11 12:34 .
drwxrwxrwx. 7 root root      4096 Nov 11 12:34 ..
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root       110 Nov 11 12:34 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root      1642 Nov 11 12:34 .gitlab-ci.yml
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root      4096 Nov 11 12:34 android-sdk-linux
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 154582459 Sep 18  2017 android-sdk.zip
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root      4096 Nov 11 12:34 app
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root       582 Nov 11 12:34 build.gradle
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root      4096 Nov 11 12:34 gradle
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root       104 Nov 11 12:34 gradle.properties
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root       484 Nov 11 12:34 settings.gradle
$ chmod +x ./gradlew
chmod: cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I missing that gradlew is actually fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual culprit was my `.gitignore` file:

```
.gitignore
--- /gradlew
    /.gradle
   @@ -1,1 @@
    gradle-wrapper.jar
    /captures/
    /gradlew.bat
    /local.properties
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
```